# Why is JQuery `$.unique()` not sorting?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have the following:

```
$(function () {
    var list = ["/62","/15","/65","/62","/15","/08","/01","/65","/62","/65","/62","/15","/01"];
    $.unique(list);
    console.log(list);
});
```

The output is:

```
["/01", "/65", "/62", "/65", "/08", "/15"]
```

https://api.jquery.com/jquery.unique/ says:

```
The $.unique() function searches through an array of objects, sorting the array, and removing any duplicate nodes.
```

Are the two "/65" considered to be different? If so, why does:

```
$(function () {
    var list = ["/62","/15","/65","/62","/15","/08","/01","/65","/62","/65","/62","/15","/01"];
    $.unique(list);
    $.unique(list);
    console.log(list);
});
```

produce:

```
["/15", "/08", "/62", "/65", "/01"]
```

And why are the ones that start with "/0" not at the beginning of the output?

Comment: it takes an array of dom elements, not objects. _"Sorts an array of DOM elements, in place, with the duplicates removed. Note that this only works on arrays of DOM elements, not strings or numbers."_

Comment: ["/62","/15","/65","/62","/15","/08","/01","/65","/62","/65","/62","/15","/01"].filter(function(a,b,c){return c.indexOf(a)===b;});

Comment: with 13 elements in the array, perf should be the last criterion. using string keys as uniques means that [1], 1, and "1" all conflict...

Comment: ok, fine. here's a faster version that's still not too complicated: ["/62","/15","/65","/62","/15","/08","/01","/65","/62","/65","/62","/15","/01"].filter(function(a,b,c){ if(this.indexOf(a)==-1)return this.push(a);},[]);

Comment: @Chris Jester-Young: http://jsperf.com/hash-vs-indexof-2 --- any comments on implementations/results?

Comment: @zerkms I personally wouldn't test for `list[i] in hash` (and just insert into hash unconditionally), but, yes, for this small data set, even removing that test, the hash approach is still 75% slower than the indexOf approach. Fair enough.

Comment: @zerkms Since this thread has gotten so long, I'm going to trim my comments off soon. BTW, I just noticed that you're also a 100k+ Kiwi! (Okay, maybe Kiwi is too strong of a word, reading your CV. But at least you live in New Zealand.) Well met, and I concede your point that there's a time and place to use linear searching.

Comment: @ChrisJester-Young I don't know if you care, but I found this conversation interesting and wanted to look into more solutions. I took some from the comments and jsperf, and added some of my own: http://jsperf.com/uniquify-array-hash-vs-indexof . Which restored my faith in hash lookups, because these comments and your jsperf worried me. There's still more solutions, including `array.forEach` (but I can't imagine it faster than a `for` loop), or a `while` loop (forwards or backwards). Ignoring speed, hash lookups aren't as complex as `indexOf`, so I'd prefer them anyways

Comment: @Ian Of course, for 2000 elements, hashes are better (and the more elements there are, the better hashes will scale). Nobody is disputing that. The discussion that zerkms and I were having was whether the `indexOf` solution is slow for the small array that the OP is working with.

Answer (score 0):

As you can surmise from the long comment thread, `$.unique` is the wrong thing to use. Instead, use Underscore's `_.uniq`.